# Django ORM .values() not works properly

Tags: django, python-3.7, django-orm

This code dos not work:

```
analyzer_signs = Sign.objects.filter(is_analyzer_used=True).values('code', 'name')
for analyzer_sign in analyzer_signs:
    print(analyzer_sign)
```

It prints nothing (doesn't enter the cycle)

But when I delete `.values('code', 'name')` - It works greate:

```
analyzer_signs = Sign.objects.filter(is_analyzer_used=True)
for analyzer_sign in analyzer_signs:
    print(analyzer_sign)
```

And I even can print text from fields **code** and **name**.

I don't know what's going on. And no one of my teammates doesn't.
Please, help!

Here is the model code:

```
class ShortNameMixin(models.Model):
    short_name = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True  #

class CodeMixin(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=125)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class AbstractBaseItem(common_models.CommonInfoAutoIncrementPK):
    name = models.TextField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SimpleDirectoryItem(ShortNameMixin, CodeMixin, AbstractBaseItem):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Sign(SimpleDirectoryItem):
    additional_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
....
    is_analyzer_used = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    alias = 'it-is-allias'

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'signtable'
        unique_together = ('sign_type', 'name',)
        ordering = default_ordering
        default_permissions = ()
        permissions = (.......)
```

PS: I tried to install differents db dumps, launched this project on Linux Mint (virtualbox) and Windows - still not works! But my teammates says "It works on my machine"... Can you suppose, what the problem is? Any help!

Comment: I've tried your code locally and it works, have you changed somewhere your objects Manager?

Comment: put *values* before *filter*: `analyzer_signs = Sign.objects.values('code', 'name').filter(is_analyzer_used=True)`

Comment: Check directly in the database if you have those fields, maybe when you run migrations it did not apply, check migrations with the app name *python manage.py makemigrations myapp1...*

Comment: @Nicolae Order between `values` and `filter` shouldn't matter, they both return a queryset that can continuously be chained. Your second comment might help, give us a hint though.

Comment: @BernardoDuarte As I know - No. It is a big legacy project, so I'm don't sure, by it works for my teammates

Comment: @Nicolae Fields THERE ARE in db, and I can get their values by using .code and .name and so on